# regex to get string inside text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex on the following string to get the content of it.

```
Dump Uuid
size=16: 
00000000: 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  *..\..S...E.c.:.6*
```

I need to get the information on the middle of the string, that would be `00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36`.
But I'm not familiar to regex, and I know I will have to get after : and before * So far I know that '**:.*$**' gets after the : , but I don't know how to limit it till *

Thanks.

Comment: where is the * in that string?

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html something like `:([^*]+)` would match everything between `:` and `*`. This is an complemented character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '00000000: 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  *..\..S...E.c.:.6*'
# this will split the string into a list 
# ['00000000', ' 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  ', '..\\..S...E.c.', '.6', '']
# next we apply the strings index in the list

import re
print(re.split(r'[:*]',s)[1])

00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36
```

Answer (score 1):

well assuming it always has the same format you could do:

```
' '.join(text.split(' ')[1:-1])
```

or

```
text.split(': ')[1].split(' *')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

To match or capture "everything up to a certain character", I usually use an inverted character set: `[abc]` will match `a` or `b` or `c`. `[^abc]` will match everything but `a`, `b`, and `c`. So the pattern

```
": ([^*]+)"
```

will match the leading colon, followed by a blank, followed by one or more "non-stars". The parentheses form a matching group that enables us to access only the relevant part:

```
inputStr = '00000000: 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  *..\..S...E.c.:.6*'
print(re.search(": ([^*]+)", inputStr).group(1).strip())
```

gives

```
'00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way

```
s = '00000000: 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36 * ....S...E.c.:.6*'
mat = re.match(r'^.*: (.*)  \*.*$', s) #get characters before :, group characters between : and *, match rest of string
if mat:
    print mat.group(1)

00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36
```

Or instead of matching the entire string you could use search like so

```
mat = re.search(r': (.*)  \*', s)

00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but why `.match` instead of `.search`?

Comment: @Jasper Search will only return the first occurrence of the matched string but it doesn't really matter since there will only be one occurrence anyway

Comment: since OP only seems to expect one occurrence, I'd prever `.search`, because the engine can stop scanning after the relevant part.

Comment: @Jasper I updated my answer to include a `.search` method. I did not know it stopped after finding the relevant part but now that you say that it makes sense.

Comment: I actually don't "know" it, I'm just assuming it, because everything else would make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `''.split()`?

```
>>> myStr = '00000000: 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  *..\..S...E.c.:.6*'
>>> myOutput = myStr.split(':')[1].split('*')[0].strip()
```

The `split(':')[1]` gives you `' 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  *..\..S...E.c.:.6*'` and then `split('*')[0]` gives you `' 00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36  '`, and then `strip()` removes the leading and trailing whitespace, so you get `'00 0C 5C 99 99 99 CB 11-BE 45 A9 63 DE 3A EF 36'`

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the string, can you not use split?

Yourtext.split(':')

Comment: What about the part after `*`?

Comment: @Alex.S it's like so `print string.split(':')[1].split('*')[0]` Didn't know full solution is expected and thanks for the downvotes